# If my application using redisson RMapCache goes down for some time, can i restore it?

Tags: redisson

I want to use Redisson RMapCache to set expiry for individual entries in a map. Now if my application crashes in betweeen, and then comes up will the keys which were supposes to expire in then downtime be expired as soon as it comes up ?
Or do i need to look at something other than redisson for this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then comes up will the keys which were supposes to expire in then downtime be expired as soon as it comes up ?

Yes, they will.